# Upgrade to Prism 8 is causing navigation errors

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Environment

- Xamarin Forms: 5.0.0.1709-pre4 (but also fails with 4.8.0.1687)
- VS2019 16.8.3
- XCode: 12.2

Prism NuGets

- Prism.DryIoc.Extensions 8.0.48
- Prism.Forms 8.0.0.1909
- Prism.PluginPopups 8.0.31-beta
- Shiny.Prism 8.0.48

Inner Exception from INavigationResult:  DryIoc.ContainerException -> InvalidOperationException

```
    code: Error.UnableToResolveFromRegisteredServices;
    message: Unable to resolve Resolution root IRMobile.PageModels.LandingPageModel with passed arguments 
    [Constant(Prism.Navigation.ErrorReportingNavigationService, 
    typeof(Prism.Navigation.ErrorReportingNavigationService))]
      from container with scope {Name=null}
     with Rules with {TrackingDisposableTransients, UseDynamicRegistrationsAsFallbackOnly, 
    FuncAndLazyWithoutRegistration, SelectLastRegisteredFactory} and without 
    {ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient, UseFastExpressionCompilerIfPlatformSupported}
     with FactorySelector=SelectLastRegisteredFactory
     with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments}
      with normal and dynamic registrations:
      (DefaultDynamicKey(0), {FactoryID=317, ImplType=IRMobile.PageModels.LandingPageModel, 
    Reuse=TransientReuse, HasCondition})
```

Stack Trace from InnerException:

```
  at DryIoc.Container.TryThrowUnableToResolve (DryIoc.Request request) [0x00058] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:1077 
  at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IContainer.ResolveFactory (DryIoc.Request request) [0x00072] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:1059 
  at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheKeyed (System.Int32 serviceTypeHash, System.Type serviceType, System.Object serviceKey, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Object scopeName, System.Type requiredServiceType, DryIoc.Request preResolveParent, System.Object[] args) [0x000c5] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:471 
  at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve (System.Type serviceType, System.Object serviceKey, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Type requiredServiceType, DryIoc.Request preResolveParent, System.Object[] args) [0x00042] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:430 
  at DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve (DryIoc.IResolver resolver, System.Type serviceType, System.Object[] args, DryIoc.IfUnresolved ifUnresolved, System.Type requiredServiceType, System.Object serviceKey) [0x00000] in /_/src/DryIoc/Container.cs:7809 
  at Prism.DryIoc.DryIocContainerExtension.Resolve (System.Type type, System.ValueTuple`2[System.Type,System.Object][] parameters) [0x0001c] in /_/external/Prism/src/Containers/Prism.DryIoc.Shared/DryIocContainerExtension.cs:294
```

App.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            // for RgPopups
            containerRegistry.RegisterPopupNavigationService();
            containerRegistry.RegisterPopupDialogService();

            // Essentials
            containerRegistry.Register<ISecureStorage, SecureStorageImplementation>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppInfo, AppInfoImplementation>();

            // page stuff
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<IconNavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IPageBehaviorFactory, CustomPageBehaviorFactory>();

            ...
            // Page and model registrations
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginPageModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LandingPage, LandingPageModel>();

        }
```

I get this exeption when trying to navigate to a root master/detail page from a LoginPage

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/LandingPage")
```

and the constructor for the LandingPage is

```
public LandingPageModel(INavigationService navigationService, IMapper mapper, IDialogs dialogs, IPushManager pushManager) : base(navigationService, mapper)
```

I am fairly new to Prism so I'm sure I am missing something, a registration or maybe a NuGet package, but I'm not sure what it would be.  I commented out the Registrations for Popup as I was getting the same error, but referring to `Prism.Plugin.Popups.PopupPageNavigationService`

As always, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are attempting to navigate to a page called LandingPage, but you haven't told the container what LandingPage is.

Every time you want to create a new view and navigate to it, you need to register it for Navigation inside your App.Xaml.cs file;

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LandingPage, LandingPageViewModel>();
```

This line registers the view and its corresponding ViewModel inside the container. Once the container knows about the view, the NavigationService can resolve the view you wish to navigate to using the literal name of the view `LandingPage`.

Now you can call

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LandingPage");
//or
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/NavigationPage/LandingPage")
```

**NOTE**

Prism navigation has a couple of neat tricks built into it. It is Uri based, so every time you navigate to another view, passing the name of the view in the NavigateAsync method will stack the view on top of the others. This means that if you start at the URI `NavigationPage/PageA`, if you then say `NavigateAsync("PageB")` you will end up at `NavigationPage/PageA/PageB`.

Additionally, including the `/` character at the very beginning of the NavigateAsync argument completely resets the stack. So if you navigate to `/PageC` from `NavigationPage/PageA/PageB`, this resets the stack to just `PageC`

Comment: Sorry, need to update the description, the "..." is where all the pages were registered.  So, the Landing page and LandingPageModel are truely register.

Comment: Before navigating, assign the result of NavigateAsync to a variable and see what the NavigationResult is. If it is false, you should be able to view the inner exception in order to better diagnose the cause. What is IDialogs exactly? I don't see it being registered inside the container.

Also I'm going to pull you up on your naming conventions. the LandingPageModel should really be called LandingPageViewModel. The model is the class that you interact with through the viewmodel

Comment: Yes, the exception above is from the INavigationResult of that Navigation.  I added the exceptions types and the stack trace.  Re: naming conventions, this is a migration from FreshMVVM (over 100 pages) so for now, since the container registrations allow it, we are keeping the "PageModel" naming convention.  May refactor at a later date.

Comment: Add INavigationAware to the page you are navigating to and see if the page is actually starting the navigation process

Comment: I had INavigatedAware, switched it to INavigationAware and had the same exception after navigation.  What is odd, is it navigates to the login page just fine, that's the initial navigation from App.xaml.cs

Comment: When you navigate to the LandingPage from the Login Page, that's when you get the exception?